# Custom semi-generalized Factory for ViewModels

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to create a generalized ViewModelProvider.Factory to instantiate my ViewModels

```
class BundledAppFactory(private var bundle: AppParameterBundle) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    Log.d("Factory", "Creating ${modelClass.canonicalName}")
    Log.d("Factory", "${modelClass.canonicalName} has ${modelClass.constructors.size} constructors and ${modelClass.declaredConstructors.size} declaredConstructors")

    modelClass.constructors.forEach {
        Log.d("Factory", "Constructor: $it")
    }
    return when {
        AppViewModel::class.java.isAssignableFrom(modelClass)               -> modelClass.getDeclaredConstructor(AppParameterBundle::class.java).newInstance(bundle)
        AppTeamUserViewModel::class.java.isAssignableFrom(modelClass)       -> modelClass.getDeclaredConstructor(AppTeamUserParameterBundle::class.java).newInstance(bundle)
        AppTeamUserHuntIdViewModel::class.java.isAssignableFrom(modelClass) -> modelClass.getDeclaredConstructor(AppTeamUserHuntIdParameterBundle::class.java).newInstance(bundle)
        AppStringViewModel::class.java.isAssignableFrom(modelClass)         -> modelClass.getDeclaredConstructor(AppStringParameterBundle::class.java).newInstance(bundle)
        else                                                                -> super.create(modelClass)
    }
}
}
```

These are my bundles:

```
open class AppParameterBundle(val application: Application)

class AppStringParameterBundle(app: Application, val string: String) : AppParameterBundle(app)

class AppTeamUserParameterBundle(app: Application,
                             val team: Team,
                             val user: User) : 
AppParameterBundle(app)

class AppTeamUserHuntIdParameterBundle(app: Application,
                                   val huntId: String,
                                   val team: Team,
                                   val user: User) : AppParameterBundle(app)
```

And these are the base ViewModels that I extend with custom ViewModels:

```
abstract class AppViewModel<MODEL, EVENT : Any>(bundle: AppParameterBundle) : BaseViewModel<MODEL, EVENT>(bundle)
abstract class AppTeamUserViewModel<MODEL, EVENT : Any>(bundle: AppTeamUserParameterBundle) : BaseViewModel<MODEL, EVENT>(bundle)
abstract class AppTeamUserHuntIdViewModel<MODEL, EVENT : Any>(bundle: AppTeamUserHuntIdParameterBundle) : BaseViewModel<MODEL, EVENT>(bundle)
abstract class AppStringViewModel<MODEL, EVENT : Any>(bundle: AppStringParameterBundle) : BaseViewModel<MODEL, EVENT>(bundle)
```

And an example of a ViewModel that extends from one of these:

```
class TeamViewModel(bundle: AppParameterBundle) : AppViewModel<TeamUiModel, TeamEvent>(bundle) {
...
}
```

My problem is that

```
modelClass.getDeclaredConstructor(AppParameterBundle::class.java).newInstance(bundle)
```

will not find any constructor and this lines

```
Log.d("Factory", "${modelClass.canonicalName} has ${modelClass.constructors.size} constructors and ${modelClass.declaredConstructors.size} declaredConstructors")
```

comes up as this in the logs

```
mypackage.viewmodels.TeamViewModel has 0 constructors and 0 declaredConstructors
```

This is what I get in the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class mypackage.ParameterBundle]
                                                   at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:528)
                                                   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:507)
                                                   at mypackage.viewmodels.BundledAppFactory.create(FactoriesAndBundles.kt:39)
                                                   at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:128)
                                                   at mypackage.TeamActivity.onCreate(TeamActivity.kt:41)
```

Is this a Kotlin problem that there are no constructors? How do I fix this?

Comment: It's not a direct solution to the problem, but you should not use reflection if not necessary. Why don't you just call a constructor directly?

Answer (score 0):

It was a Proguard problem. 
I had to add this lines to the .pro rules file

```
-keep class mypackage.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers public class mypackage.** { *; }
```